# How can I create a Query that looks at a field and pulls the 3 characters that appear after a comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I create a Query that looks at a field and pulls the 3 characters that appear after a comma -- EACH entry in this field has a comma and characters after it.

Basically I have a field that has CITY, STATE and sometimes the zipcode after it

I want it to pull the 2 letter State code that appears after the , and the space following the comma

Comment: Do you mean from the field "name" with value "Ninja,Mary", get "Mary"?

Comment: what database system are you using?

Comment: Hi Hogan! -- the field name (Column heading) is ShipAddress4. The entries are all City,States but sometimes the entry is City,State  Zipcode.. I am hoping to return the 3 characters AFTER the comma and nothing else :)

Comment: Also, using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, count)
```

See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) for documentation.

Comment: So how would I type it out if the field name is called ShipAddress4

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mytestpage.info','.',2);
```

for more information
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php

Comment: You put this up before.. how would i type that out if the field i need to look at is named "ShipAddress4".....  

DECLARE @Sentence    VARCHAR(MAX) = 'LAREDOTX,78041'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Sentence, CHARINDEX(',', @Sentence)+1 , 3) AS [Second Word]

Comment: @Ninja-Mary i didnt get ur question?

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL, as you didn't specify the SQL dialect:

```
substring(col from position(',' in col)+1 for 3)
```

Comment: So how would I type it out if the field name is called ShipAddress4

Comment: `substring(ShipAddress4 from position(',' in col)+1 for 3)`, but you already got a SQL Server version :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT RIGHT(@str, LEN(@str) - CHARINDEX(',', @str) - 1)
```

Comment: So how would I type it out if the field name is called ShipAddress4

Comment: SELECT RIGHT(ShipAddress4 , LEN(ShipAddress4 ) - CHARINDEX(',', ShipAddress4) - 1)

Answer (score 0):

in MS SQL Server having the value of a field as `'LAREDOTX,78041'`, do something like:

```
  DECLARE @Sentence    VARCHAR(MAX) = 'LAREDOTX,78041'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Sentence, CHARINDEX(',', @Sentence)+1 , 3) AS [Second Word]
```

Getting as result:

```
Second Word
---------
780
```

Comment: So how would I type it out if the field name is called  ShipAddress4

The contents of the field vary, different City,States --etc